# Presence, PubNub + Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pubnub

I'm trying to use the presence features of PubNub and relay the info received back as a normal message. Below is my subscribe function that is working properly as well as my here_now that doesn't give me anything. I guess what I'm wondering is how and why they differ. Pointers on proper implementation are also of great value.

```
pubnub.here_now({
  'channel'  => @channel, 
  'callback' => lambda do |x|
## Relay Message
   sendMessage(x)
return true
end
})

pubnub.subscribe({
  'channel'  => @channel, 
  'callback' => lambda do |message|
## Relay Message
   sendMessage(message)        
return true
end
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For very simple test with what you have provided, you will want to run the subscribe in one ruby script, first, then run the publish script in the here_now script separately.